# Which driver to use for configuring PS PCIe Endpoint on Zynq MPsoc device

Tags: pci

I'm trying to configure Zynq MPSoc as a PS PCIe Endpoint device,
From my research, I think maybe NWL driver doesn't support PS Endpoint functionality but only supports Root Port.

Then I found out about PS PCIe EP DMA driver, which can be used for Endpoint functionality. But there is no resource regarding same.

If anyone has used it before, any information regarding the same would push me in right direction.